# How to find development information about struct timespec

Tags: c, manpage

I'm writing a C program using `nftw()` to walk a filesystem and retrieve file modification times for each file.

`nftw()` calls a supplied function pointer and provides a `struct stat` as an argument.

`man stat(2)` states that the time modification fields are:

```
struct timespec st_atim;  /* time of last access */
struct timespec st_mtim;  /* time of last modification */
struct timespec st_ctim;  /* time of last status change */
```

However, whilst `man stat(2)` provides an example of how to print the time fields, it doesn't tell me how to find information about `struct timespec`, nor how to query/manipulate the time modification fields.

How should I go about finding that information on my computer alone, without resorting to Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically one of the man pages describes what these structures contain. If you tell us your platform I can give further details. Otherwise, open up the header `/usr/include/time.h` to see what `struct timespec` is defined as.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 15.10 64bit.

Comment: I'm guessing you know to open up time.h from experience. The man page makes no reference to that header. How could I have come to that conclusion myself?

Comment: @retrodev [POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html) that this is the place where `struct timespec` is declared.

Comment: @retrodev You could also search for `struct timespec` in `/usr/include` to find potential declarations.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ apropos timespec
clock_gettime        (2)  - Return the current timespec value of tp for the specified clock
$ man 2 clock_gettime
```

Comment: On my system, the answer to the first query is “timespec: nothing appropriate.” Should I return my system?

Comment: No. You should use google, or if you _really_ don't want to, you can grep your include path. But why would you?

Comment: I also get "timespec: nothing appropriate".

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when I need information on data types or functions, if not included in the man pages, I issue a command like the following:

`grep -r "timespec" /usr/include/`

in the path where are the header files.